# Using ColdFusion variable with line breaks in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I have a text area that accepts line breaks. The content of that text area is saved in a coldfusion variable (lets call it `#fieldVal#`). So, my variable contents look like

```
textline 1
textline 2
```

Later on, I use that variable in JavaScript

```
document.all.fieldName.value = "#fieldVal#";
```

However, when the JavaScript hits the page, it looks like this:

```
document.all.fieldName.value = "textline 1
textline 2";
```

and the script breaks because the first line doesn't end in a semicolon.

I tried setting a JavaScript variable to the ColdFusion text then doing a `replace()`, but I still hit the same issue with the line not ending correctly.

I think I'm missing something obvious but I am just not seeing it. Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: what is the specific error it mentions?

Comment: SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant

Comment: Did you try either <cfwddx> or toScript() ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the JSStringFormat() function.  It is designed to escape meta characters in JavaScript

> Escapes special JavaScript characters, such as single-quotation mark,
>   double-quotation mark, and newline.

https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/JSStringFormat

```
document.all.fieldName.value = "#JSStringFormat( fieldVal )#";
```

If you're using ColdFusion 10+ or Lucee Server, use `EncodeForJavaScript()`.

https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/EncodeForJavaScript

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

```
document.all.fieldName.value = "#Replace(trim(fieldVal), chr(10) & chr(13), ' ', 'ALL')#";
```

**Option 2** (Possible that the same issue occur in this too.)

Try using [`ToScript()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ToScript)

```
ToScript(fieldVal, valueVar)
```

Toscript initializes a variable with the coldfusion variable value and you can use like any JS global variable.

```
document.all.fieldName.value = valueVar;
```

**Option 3** (If you need in HTML form)

Use coldfusion function [`ParagraphFormat()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ParagraphFormat) which changes line breaks into `<br/>`.

Comment: Options 1 and to 3 don't handle other special characters that might be in the string.

Comment: @BradWood yes that true, i'll try to improve it. :)

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled upon a code snippet that worked. Its a bit...convoluted, but it works.

```
document.all.fieldName.value = "#Replace(Replace(URLDecode(Replace(Replace(URLEncodedFormat(fieldVal), "%0D", " ", "ALL"), "%0A", "", "ALL")),CHR(34),"", "ALL"),CHR(39),"", "ALL")#"
```

Comment: That is a mess and completely unnecessary.  CFML has a function that I mentioned in my answer that cleanly handles this.  JSStringFormat().

Comment: yeah, I found this snippet elsewhere in the system. I'll probably go and replace it with the function from your answer later today.